# Attempting nil with CFrame

Tags: lua, roblox

So , this is babblo , say hi to him [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo8xn.jpg)

So Babblo is an Pet model that i need to move , problem with that i can not , so there are three parts where the pet can move to PetTeleportationPart 1 2 and 3 where Babblo can be teleported to , see yourself

```
local PrimaryPart = workspace:WaitForChild("Pet").PrimaryPart

PrimaryPart.Position = workspace:FindFirstChild("PetTeleportationPart1").Position
```

Whats This Tab , well i am just gonna post the code here again :

```
local PrimaryPart = workspace:WaitForChild("Pet").PrimaryPart

PrimaryPart.Position = workspace:FindFirstChild("PetTeleportationPart1").Position
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to `WaitForChild(“PrimaryPart”)` because if it tries to access it before it is loaded it will return `nil` thus your attempting nil with CFrame.

Hope this helps!